# How to subscribe to HTTP response which contains dynamic key value pair?

Tags: angular

My api response returns a dynamic key value pair something like,

```
{
    'prop3': 'value5', 
    'prop2': 'value1', 
    'prop5': 'value4', 
    'prop1': 'value2', 
    'prop4': 'value3', 
  };
```

I'm getting the response in service, how to subscribe to response in component.

Also i want to make use of angular material table. So how can i achieve with this?

api.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http'
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });  
  _baseUrl: string = '';  
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
    this._baseUrl = "https://beta.randomapi.com/api/3141b5683af0edf576dabdb50ef1ff64?fmt=prettyraw&sole"; 
   }
   public GetAllRecords(): Observable<any> {  
    return this.http.get(this._baseUrl);

  }
```

app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  displayedColumns=['key','value'];
  dataSource:any;
  checked: boolean = false;
  RenderDataTable() {  
    this.apiService.GetAllRecords().subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.dataSource=new MatTableDataSource();
      this.dataSource.data=res;


    });  



  }  
  constructor(public apiService:ApiService){

  }
  ngOnInit(){
   this.RenderDataTable();
  }
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource | keyvalue"  > 
  <ng-container matColumnDef="key">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Key </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.key}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Value </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.value}} </td>
  </ng-container>

<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

in service :-

```
getData() {
  return this.http.get(url);
]
```

in component

```
service.getData().subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Best practices](https://angular.io/guide/http) suggest you to define all your http requests as methods in an injectable service, then the component injects the service and subscribe to the service methods. (Check "Requesting data from a server" section from the link I suggested).

From angular guide, your service method could be like:

```
getConfig() {
  return this.http.get(this.configUrl);
}
```

And your component could use it this way:

```
constructor(private _configService: ConfigService) {}

this._configService.getConfig()
    .subscribe((data: Config) => this.config = {
        heroesUrl: data['heroesUrl'],
        textfile:  data['textfile']
    });
```

You can then use your data on material table, I suggest you to follow the [getting started with angular material](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) guide and then follow [this](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#getting-started) to use data you got as dataSource for your table.

Hope it helps!